# Using a Java8 Lambda Function inside spring XML

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class FooToBarTransformer {
    public Bar transform(Foo foo) {
        // do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

And I want to consume it as a `Function` in some other class:

```
public class Thing {
    public Thing(Function<Foo, Bar> f) {
        this.converter = f;
    }
}
```

Now, if I'm instantiating a `Thing` through Java, I'd do it with Java8 Lambdas like this:

```
FooToBarTransformer transformer = new FooToBarTransformer();
new Thing((foo) -> transformer.transform(foo));
// or new Thing(transformer::transform);
```

**My problem, is that I need to create a `Thing` though spring**.

```
<bean id="fooToBarTransformer" class="com.mypackage.FooToBarTransformer"/>
<bean id="theThing" class="com.mypackage.Thing">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ????????? />
</bean>
```

Now, there are a few possible workarounds I've considered to make this easier:

1. if `FooToBarTransformer` implemented `Function`, then it would just be a simple `ref="fooToBarTransformer"`
2. I could create a different interface that `FooToBarTransformer` implements and change `Thing` to take an instance of that interface instead of `Function`.  For the purpose of this question, neither of those are options.

Based on some other ways I've seen of doing executions in the spring xml, I've tried `value="#{(foo) -> fooToBarTransformer.transform(foo)}"` and `value="#{fooToBarTransformer::transform}"` but spring choked on this.

The best option I've come up with so far is to provide a translation function in code:

```
public Function<Foo, Bar> toFunction() {
    return transformer::transform;
}
```

and reference it in spring with `value="#{fooToBarTransformer.toFunction()}"`, but this seems rather hokey.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Side note: `new Thing(transformer::transform);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651157/how-to-declare-a-java-8-method-reference-in-a-spring-xml-file

Comment: Basically, you can't. There is no notation to support it at the moment.

Comment: Boo-urns. Well, at least it's an answer instead of me wondering forever...

Comment: Why CAN'T your `FooToBarTransformer` implement `Function<Foo,Bar>`? You just add `public Bar apply(Foo foo){return transform(foo);}` to it.

Comment: @SteveK - it'd be an option if I had complete control of the class.. Sadly I do not have that control.

Comment: If you can add a `toFunction()` method, you can modify the class. You could also extend the class into a `FooToBarTransformerFunction` and implement `Function` there, without modifying the original class (but any changes to the original class would be reflected in your subclass)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to do is to switch to Java Config (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java)
In the meantime, if you can't switch, you can still pull it off by combining methods. In you're XML configuration file add:

```
<bean class="com.myapp.config.FooBarConfiguration"/>
```

Then, you create class `com.myapp.config.FooBarConfiguration` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class FooBarConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FooToBarTransformer fooTransformer() {
        return new FooToBarTransformer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Thing theThing(FooToBarTransformer fooTransformer) {
        return new Thing(fooTransformer::transform);
    }
}
```

Just make sure that `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` is a registered post-processor in your Spring context by either having:

`<context:annotation-config>`

Or

`<context:component-scan>`

Or by manually adding the post processor as a bean:

`<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor"/>`

This should work from Spring 3.0 and above according with http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.html. Not sure what version you're using.

Comment: Question was about xml configuration - switching to Java config is (imo) not a valid answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use factory pattern. See org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean.
Also spring has expression language.